# Extra charge for a payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I want to add a feature by which I can charge a specific amount to the customer when he use Cash on Delivery but no extra charge when he uses the payment gateway in magento 1.9X.?
kindly provide a solution.

Comment: Did you try this extensionhttps://magecomp.com/magento-payment-fee.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this extension, but before that test in staging or demo site : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cash-on-delivery-3.html

or

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cash-on-delivery-extra-charges.html

```
<?php
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer 
{

    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');
        $returnValue = false;
        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        if($quote->getEntityId()!='')
        {
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');
                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;
                if(strlen($postcode) >= 6) {
                    if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                        $result->isAvailable = true;
                    } else {    

                        if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                            $isExist = true;
                        }

                        if($isExist != true) {

                            $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                            if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                                foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                    $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                    if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                        $isExist = true;
                                        break;
                                    } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                        $isExist = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;
                        $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;
                    }
                }
                $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;   
}
            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: link does not exist

Comment: @Baby in Magento, Links are not available, check again

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara thanks for informing, i updated code.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento, you are welcome, I am suggesting you please add the file    path and edit the urls of existed